# Regex not working properly, syntax is right on regexr for replacing multiple backslash

Tags: java, regex, string

need to mask the clientSecret which would a dynamic value
input String

`data: \"{\\\"clientId\\\":\\\"my-client-id\\\",\\\"clientSecret\\\":\\\"secret\\\"}\"`

matcher

`.replaceAll("(clientSecret\\*\":\\*\")[^\"]*", "$1*****\\\\\\")`

or

`.replaceAll("(clientSecret\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\")[^\"]*", "$1*****\\\\\\")`

expected would be

`data: \"{\\\"clientId\\\":\\\"my-client-id\\\",\\\"clientSecret\\\":\\\"*****\\\"}\"`

tried regexr and it works

ps update made a java code:

```
String testString = "data: \\\"{\\\\\\\"clientId\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"my-client-id\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"clientSecret\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"secret\\\\\\\"}\\\"";
System.out.println(testString.replaceAll("(clientSecret\\*\":\\*\")[^\"]*", "$1*****\\\\\\"));
System.out.println(testString.replaceAll("(clientSecret\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\")[^\"]*", "$1*****\\\\\\"));
```

output would be
`data: \"{\\\"clientId\\\":\\\"my-client-id\\\",\\\"clientSecret\\\":\\\"secret\\\"}\"`

Comment: Can you show the actual output, so we can see which bit you think is going wrong?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem it didnt mask any string so no change in from the input and the output. but it would work if i just replace clientSecret string itself not the value

Comment: It looks just fine to me.  How are you reading that input string into a Java variable though?  Is it in a file somewhere, or some other data source, or are you trying to use it as a literal?  If it's a literal, you'll need to escape all the backslash and double quote characters in it.

Comment: `replaceAll("secret","******");`

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Hi I've added a sample code

Comment: @DevilsHnd the value would be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `replaceAll` is a regular expression.  Which means that when you're looking for

```
"(clientSecret\\*\":\\*\")[^\"]*"
```

you need to escape the backslashes from the regular expression parser, as well as from the Java compiler.  In other words, to match a single backslash in the target, you need to write four backslashes in your Java.  The term you match should have been written as

```
"(clientSecret\\\\*\":\\\\*\")[^\"]*"
```

Otherwise, you're actually matching a single asterisk, each time you intended to match multiple backslashes.

Comment: Already escaped the characters meaning clientsecret + any number of back slashes + ": any number of backslashes but still not working

Comment: You've escaped them from the Java compiler, but not from the regular expression parser.  You need to escape them twice.  What you wrote matches an asterisk, not a bunch of backslashes.